# Conditional query Prisma assigning a value using date

Tags: prisma

I want to find the menus type provided by the restaurant (breakfast type) according to the time now, and the hours to display is on ShowingHours model

I created a Menu model

```
model Menu {
  id             String         @id @default(cuid())
  type           String?
  branchId       String
  branch         Branch         @relation(fields: [branchId], references: [id])
  menuCategories MenuCategory[]

  ShowingHours   ShowingHours? @relation(fields: [showingHoursId], references: [id])
  showingHoursId String?
}
```

and ShowingHours

```
model ShowingHours {
  id         String  @id @default(cuid())
  fromHour   Int?
  fromMinute Int?
  toHour     Int?
  toMinute   Int?
  allDay     Boolean
  menus      Menu[]
}
```

```
    let timeNow = new Date().getHours();
```

I want to make a condition that if the value of timeNow for example is 9 am, then query a menu that has a inbetween timenow hours from "fromHour" to "toHour"

My approach:

```
let menuType = await db.menu.findMany({
      // between fromhour tohour
     where: {
      branchId: branchId,
//I WOULD LIKE TO MAKE A CONDITION LIKE: if timeNow >= fromHour && timenow < toHour then fetch 
      ShowingHours: {
        OR: [
          {
            fromHour: {
              in: 
            }
          }
        ]
      }
      },
     
      
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [lt](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#lt) and [gt](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#gt) comparison operators to form the query.

It could look something like this:

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  log: [{ level: 'query', emit: 'stdout' }],
});

async function main() {
  let timeNow = new Date().getHours();
  
  await prisma.menu.findMany({
    where: {
      branchId: '1',
      ShowingHours: {
        AND: [
          {
            fromHour: {
              lt: timeNow,
            },
          },
          {
            toHour: {
              gt: timeNow,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
}

main()
  .catch((e) => {
    throw e;
  })
  .finally(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  });
```